# How to set a Number field with a different Number type using Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, numbers, javabeans

Our original code is something like:

```
Object bean = ...
Field field = ...
Object value = ... // Retrieved from Database
field.set(bean, value);
```

But the type of bean field may be different from type of value, e.g. our bean is an `Integer` but value retrieved from db may be `Byte` or `Short`.

How can I write some simple code to convert boxed types without reflection exception?

Here is my solution but not as simple as my expectation:

```
if (field.getType().equals(Integer.class)) {
   field.set(bean, Integer.valueOf(((Number) value).intValue()));
} else if (field.getType().equals(Short.class)) {
   field.set(bean, Short.valueOf(((Number) value).shortValue()));
} else if (...) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a simpler solution.

Comment: That's sort of the standard approach. C has a similar way of dealing with stdarg stuff. That's just the nature of marshalling and unmarshalling. You could do some very creative things with a lot more complexity to automate the deconstruction, but I think @StephenC is right.  Just create a function to decode numbers. The optimal way to do everything you need in general depends on your specific application and scope of tasks and variability of the input, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no way to handle these conversion generically unless you add even more Reflection.

The best you can do, is to make these required expressions more maintainable. One thing to consider, is that with your expressions like, e.g. `Short.valueOf(((Number) value).shortValue())`, the `valueOf` invocation is unnecessary. That’s what auto-boxing does anyway.

Then, you can do with recent Java versions:

```
static final Map<Class<?>,Setter> SETTERS =Map.copyOf(Map.<Class<?>,NumericSetter>ofEntries(
    Map.entry(byte.class, (field,bean,n) -> field.setByte(bean, n.byteValue())),
    Map.entry(short.class, (field,bean,n) -> field.setShort(bean, n.shortValue())),
    Map.entry(int.class, (field,bean,n) -> field.setInt(bean, n.intValue())),
    Map.entry(long.class, (field,bean,n) -> field.setLong(bean, n.longValue())),
    Map.entry(float.class, (field,bean,n) -> field.setFloat(bean, n.floatValue())),
    Map.entry(double.class, (field,bean,n) -> field.setDouble(bean, n.doubleValue())),
    Map.entry(Byte.class, (field,bean,n) -> field.set(bean, n.byteValue())),
    Map.entry(Short.class, (field,bean,n) -> field.set(bean, n.shortValue())),
    Map.entry(Integer.class, (field,bean,n) -> field.set(bean, n.intValue())),
    Map.entry(Long.class, (field,bean,n) -> field.set(bean, n.longValue())),
    Map.entry(Float.class, (field,bean,n) -> field.set(bean, n.floatValue())),
    Map.entry(Double.class, (field,bean,n) -> field.set(bean, n.doubleValue()))
));
interface Setter {
    void set(Field field, Object bean, Object value) throws IllegalAccessException;
    Setter FALLBACK = Field::set;
}
interface NumericSetter extends Setter {
    @Override default void set(Field field, Object bean, Object value)
    throws IllegalAccessException {
        setNumeric(field, bean, (Number)value);
    }
    void setNumeric(Field f, Object bean, Number n) throws IllegalAccessException;
}
```

To handle all numeric field types, whether primitive or boxed. This can be use like

```
SETTERS.getOrDefault(field.getType(), Setter.FALLBACK).set(field, bean, value);
```

to use one of the numeric conversions if applicable or just use the `set` method without transformations otherwise. The latter would also throw the appropriate exception for mismatching types.

For older Java versions you could consider something like

```
static boolean setNumeric(Field field, Object bean, Object value)
throws IllegalAccessException {
    if(!(value instanceof Number)) return false;
    Number n = (Number)value;
    Class<?> type = field.getType();
    if(type.isPrimitive()) {
        if(type == boolean.class || type == char.class) return false;
        switch(type.getName().charAt(0)) {
            case 'b': field.setByte(bean, n.byteValue()); break;
            case 's': field.setShort(bean, n.shortValue()); break;
            case 'i': field.setInt(bean, n.intValue()); break;
            case 'l': field.setLong(bean, n.longValue()); break;
            case 'f': field.setFloat(bean, n.floatValue()); break;
            case 'd': field.setDouble(bean, n.doubleValue()); break;
            default: throw new AssertionError(type);
        }
    }
    else {
        if(!Number.class.isAssignableFrom(type)
        || type.getPackage() != Object.class.getPackage())
            return false;
        switch(type.getSimpleName().charAt(0)) {
            case 'B': field.set(bean, n.byteValue()); break;
            case 'S': field.set(bean, n.shortValue()); break;
            case 'I': field.set(bean, n.intValue()); break;
            case 'L': field.set(bean, n.longValue()); break;
            case 'F': field.set(bean, n.floatValue()); break;
            case 'D': field.set(bean, n.doubleValue()); break;
            default: throw new AssertionError(type);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This only handles the numeric types and return the success status. The caller can use it like

```
if(!setNumeric(field, bean, value)) {
    field.set(bean, value); // non numeric or throw appropriate exception
}
```

Comment: And we also have `BigInteger`, `BigDecimal`, `AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong` and `AtomicDouble`

Comment: Do you mean, you database field returns `AtomicInteger` and such alike or do you mean the field type is `AtomicInteger`? In either case, you have to rethink your approach as that’s not how updating an `AtomicInteger` works. For the `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` cases, adding them is trivial, but you should decide which conversion directions you want to support. Setting without conversion does already work with both approaches.

Comment: db never returns `AtomicInteger` but our bean may have this type. So I'm going to write a lot based on your example code. very thanks.

Comment: Using `AtomicInteger` only makes sense when using it correctly, which implies never changing its reference. It’s also recommended to declare the field `final` to ensure that it is never used incorrectly. Hence, the update code would have to look like `(field,bean,n) -> ((AtomicInteger)field.get(bean)).set(n.intValue())`, which is entirely different than updating a mutable numeric field. You can’t handle both cases with the same code. On the other hand, if you don’t need correct atomic updates, you shouldn’t use `AtomicInteger` at all.

Comment: thank you for the advice. our modification may be something like: `if (field is AtomicInteger) { ((AtomicInteger) field.get(bean)).set(((Number) value).intValue()) } else { field.set(bean, ...) }`